# Ruby 1.8.7 calculator- NoMethodError with .to_sym

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a simple Ruby calculator as a hobby project, and I am running Ruby 1.8.7 . I can't seem to figure out how to convert my strings into symbols, and when I use .to_sym Ruby keeps on returning a noMethodError. Is there any way I can get around this without updating my Ruby version?
Thanks, Wizard.

Comment: You should post the code you're using, so we can spot the error. The best we can do now is guess.

Answer (score 2):

The `to_sym` method works fine in Ruby 1.8.7. Make sure what you're calling it on is actually a String.

```
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"
irb(main):002:0> "foo".to_sym
=> :foo
```

That said, 1.8.7 is way past end-of-life; you should really update to Ruby 2.x at this point.